# How to use a method created in a child class (not those implemented on interface) | C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I'm playing and experimenting with interfaces in C#, I'm trying to inherit from an interface to implement their methods in a child classes, but one of the child classes, I'm adding a method that is not in the interface but I can't invoke it.

How could I do that? This is what I have

Interface:

```
interface IShape
{
    double GetPerimeter();
    double GetArea();
}
```

Classes:

```
public class Square : IShape
{
     public double  GetPerimeter()
     {
         // all code here
     }

     public double GetArea()
     {
         // all code here
     }
}

public class Rectangle : IShape
{
     public double  GetPerimeter()
     {
         // all code here
     }

     public double GetArea()
     {
         // all code here
     }

     public string PrintShape()
     {
         return "This is a rectangle!"
     }
}
```

Main program:

```
IShape shape = null;
Console.WriteLine("Select Shape");
Console.WriteLine("1- Rectangle");
Console.WriteLine("2- Square");
int shapeSelected = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (shapeSelected.Equals(1))
{
     shape = new Rectangle();
}
else
{
     shape = new Square();
}
```

if I try to invoke method "PrintShape" from Rectangle class, I'm not allowed to do that, How I could use methods that are not from the interface?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use something that only exists in a class, you need a reference to that class, you cannot use the interface.

Comment: Also define an IPrintable interface, use the is or as operator to discover if an object implements it.

Comment: @HansPassant Or extend the interface, or create another one that extends it, or use a base class with the method. There are many options to solve this

Comment: Thanks for your opinions guys, I'm going to take a look in all those solutions that you've mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

You are having some misconcepts here, interfaces are just a bunch of methods your class is compelled to implement. You dont inherit interfaces, you implement it.

Now to the problem you have. Since IShape doesnt know the method PrintShape, if you define if you try to call `shape.PrintShape()`it will not compile, because of the reason i said above.

How can you solve this? You got 2 options 1 would be to cast your shape like this `((Rectangle)shape).PrintShape()` or what i recommend you to actually do, give the signature to the interface, and implement it as void in the square

Comment: Thanks for clarify the concepts, I've tried the first option that you gave me and it worked, but now I'm going to dive and explore the 2nd. option, appreciate your help @nalnpir

Comment: Javier, the first option will throw an exception if you mess up and use a square instead of a rectangle, bear that in mind, while the second solution, will always do something because every object that implements the interface IShape has to implement it. This concept is called polymorphism

Comment: Yes! that's what I thought, that it could fail due if is an square it will not find that method an throw an exception, thanks for clarifying me the concepts! doing my best to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the method is specific to that object you will have to cast your interface to that object.

```
var text = ((Rectangle)shape).PrintShape();
```

if you want to make sure it is applied only to rectangle use as and check if it is not null.

```
var rectangle = shape as Rectangle;
if (rectangle != null)
    var text = rectangle.PrintShape();
```